# Rest API Calls with RestSharp calling ASP.NET Web API

Tags: rest, asp.net-web-api, restsharp, webapi

I'm currently testing out writing a RESTful API with ASP.NET Web API. I'm using RestSharp on a client to simulate different calls.

I want to submit an application ID query string, and the body should be a collection of type "Log". Every time, the application ID get's posted by the body received by the server is always NULL.

Code on the server:

```
 public class LogsController : ApiController
{
    public HttpStatusCode Post(Guid ID, [FromBody] List<Log> logs)
    {
        if (logs != null)
            return HttpStatusCode.OK;
        else
            return HttpStatusCode.PreconditionFailed;
    }
}

public class Log
{
    public Guid ErrorId { get; set; }
}
```

Code on the client:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var client = new RestClient("http://localhost:36146/api");

        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new List<Log>()
            {
                new Log { ErrorId = Guid.NewGuid()}
            });

        var request = new RestRequest("Logs", Method.POST);

        request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
        request.AddParameter("ID", Guid.NewGuid(), ParameterType.QueryString);
        request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
        request.AddBody(json);

        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
        Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
        Console.Read();
    }

    public class Log
    {
        public Guid ErrorId { get; set; }
    }
```

I thought I got this working, however no matter what I do now the "logs" parameter on the server is always NULL.

Comment: Paul - its great toknow that you found the solution, here is a link : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/826359/Consuming-ASP-NET-WEB-API-using-ASP-NET-MVC-and-Re which describe the usage of RestSharp - might be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

I think I've found the issue.

RestSharp implicitly uses the JsonSerializer when populating the body of the request. As I was also called the Serializer I think it caused issues with the formatting.

I've removed that call to the serializer and now I'm receiving a 200 back from the server.

Happy days.

Comment: You can use this library to switch to using Json.NET - https://www.nuget.org/packages/RestSharp.Newtonsoft.Json